# rsync permissions from Windows (cygwin) to Linux server

Tags: cygwin, rsync, file-permissions

I'm trying to sync files from development machine running Windows (using cygwin) to staging server running Linux.

I tried `rsync -avz --no-p --no-g` so synced directories/files would receive default permissions, but in my case both directories and files receive 755 permission. It's fine for direcotries, but for files I would like to get 644.

I tried playing with `--chmod` but couldn't find the right combination.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and your question pointed me towards the --chmod option.  The recommended settings seem to work for me.  I'm using cygwin on a Windows 7 system syncing to a FreeBSD system.

`% rsync -rltvu --chmod=ugo=rwX Applications unixhost:/windows/backup`

Using that, the destination host received the files with directory mode 755 and file mode 644.